# What movie or fandom is this jewelry from?

Tags: object-identification

My question is about these Bracelets I got at a Garage sale about 3-4 years ago. (because i just liked the way they looked.) But now that I've been looking at them more, I'm wondering if they are from something like a movie. Two of them had like designs on them but it rubbed off on the round one. 
Theres a sphere charm on one, Another has a heart, a wolf, a motorcycle, a feather, And a flat circle one with the design. The design looks like two wolves over a triangle thing. i included pictures of all the charms below for better identification.
Does anyone know if these are from something? 
[image: all of the bracelets]

[image: round charm bracelet]

[image: back of flat circle charm bracelet]

[image: feather charm bracelet]

[image: heart charm bracelet]

[image: wolf charm bracelet]

[image: front of flat circle charm bracelet]

[image: motorcycle charm bracelet]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The disc, wolf, and heart are the [Twilight New Moon "Wolf Pack" Jelly Bangle Bracelet with Charms](https://shopzodys.com/products/twilight-new-moon-wolf-pack-jelly-bangle-bracelet-with-charms?cid=2073893203&aid=76857567752&eid=&tid=pla-293946777986&ul=9007365&mt=&n=g&d=c&dm=&dt&sn&adid=372526826767&k=&p=&pc=&ap=1o1&nnmebr=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiAz53vBRCpARIsAPPsz8Uzb0T6OzIqE1r1HBKE-IWlVhD-n98dAc5FBlxbGU5ccawi-CqIbWsaAqkaEALw_wcB):

[image: image of product]

The motorcycle, feather (or leaf?), and orb are the [Licensed Neca Jacob Tattoo Twilight New Moon Bracelets](https://www.bonanza.com/listings/Licensed-NECA-Jacob-Tattoo-Twilight-New-Moon-Bracelets/16991539?goog_pla=1&gpid=76984044181&keyword=&goog_pla=1&pos=1o17&ad_type=pla&gclid=Cj0KCQiAz53vBRCpARIsAPPsz8Wb0zeNqC1RDwCjerVfmGVXTIxgT3ZC5PZzBWPjMjr9EO9LHuvGE2UaAi4-EALw_wcB):

[image: product image]

As you can see, the pink color in your pictures used to be gold in color, and the orb used to say "Jacob".

There's also an [Edward set](https://shopzodys.com/products/twilight-new-moon-edward-lion-jelly-bangle-bracelet-with-charms?cid=2073893203&aid=76857567752&eid=&tid=pla-293946777986&ul=9007365&mt=&n=g&d=c&dm=&dt&sn&adid=372526826767&k=&p=&pc=&ap=1o3&nnmebr=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiAz53vBRCpARIsAPPsz8X1QicMWlLYQ5cEzLzkjdMtajRLQtMnnvPih7Jsc_Uh5vQksaqK428aAjz3EALw_wcB) with black bands and silver charms: an orb that says "Edward", a lion, and a heart.

Comment: It’s a wolf? I was looking for a rat...

Comment: @JamesMcLeod I really hope I never encounter a group of howling rats.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Howling rats? Hmm... https://youtu.be/1K9mO5QzOIQ?t=96

Answer (score 17):

I would assume it's related to the film *Twilight*. [Other](https://poshmark.com/listing/TM-SUMMIT-ENTERTAINMENT-LLC-RUSTIC-BRACELET-5b7739fb34a4ef0e50a27c03) similar [bracelets](https://twilightsaga.propstoreauction.com/view-auctions/catalog/id/109/lot/22701/) with wolves and hearts are available from Summit Entertainment.

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Summit Entertainment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Summit_Entertainment_films#2010s) is also punched into the coin on the third image, making it clear it's theirs.